# Add html to chrome current tab doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I want to add a button to scroll the current tab in Chrome (in Facebook), but when I add the code  the icon for scroll doesn't work but when I try it in the w3school emulator it works.

And after I do that, how can I do that it will stay every time I opened up a website?

**The code**

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Scroll</button>


<script>
// When the user scrolls down 20px from the top of the document, show the button
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction()};

function scrollFunction() {

        document.getElementById("myBtn").style.display = "block";

}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
window.scrollBy(0,100);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: How are you adding this code, and to what?    If you're trying to inject new code into all websites you visit, that would require building a browser extension, which is possible of course but not simple.

Comment: @DanielBeck I tried as you said to build a browser extension and I need to know how to make a button on the page and make the page scroll...

Comment: OK. This is much more involved than just coding up a standalone web page.  Start here and if you get stuck post a question specific to that issue: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/getstarted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally succeed!

I download the browser extension - Tampermonkey (it lets you run JavaScript on sites like browser extensions do)

And then without HTML/CSS only with JS I did it

Here's the code for those how want (scroll to the top):

```
//scroll to top smooth scrolling
var button = document.createElement ("Button");
button.innerHTML = "Top";
button.style = "display: none;bottom: 0px;right:0;position:fixed;z-index: 9999;border: none; outline: none; background-color: red; color: white; cursor: pointer; padding: 15px; border-radius: 10px";
document.body.appendChild(button);
window.onscroll = function() {scrollFunction();};

function scrollFunction() {
    if (document.body.scrollTop > 75 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 75) {
        button.style.display = "block";
    } else {
        button.style.display = "none";
    }
}
button.onmouseover=function()
{
    button.style.backgroundColor="gray";
};
button.onmouseleave=function()
{
    button.style.backgroundColor="red";
};
var i;
button.onclick = function()
{
    if(scrollY<500)
        i=100;
    else if(scrollY<1000)
        i=125;
    else if(scrollY<1500)
        i=150;
    else if(scrollY<2000)
        i=175;
    else if(scrollY<2500)
        i=200;
    else if(scrollY<10000)
        i=((scrollY/2500)*100)+125;
    else
        i=((scrollY/5000)*100)+125;
    doScrolling(0,i);
};
function doScrolling(elementY, duration) { 
    var startingY = window.pageYOffset; 
    var diff = elementY - startingY;
    var start;

    // Bootstrap our animation - it will get called right before next frame shall be rendered.
    window.requestAnimationFrame(function step(timestamp) {
        if (!start) start = timestamp;
        // Elapsed miliseconds since start of scrolling.
        var time = timestamp - start;
        // Get percent of completion in range [0, 1].
        var percent = Math.min(time / duration, 1);

        window.scrollTo(0, startingY + diff * percent);

        // Proceed with animation as long as we wanted it to.
        if (time < duration) {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(step);
        }
    });
}
```